# why is Exact Target FUEL SDK not validating my API keys?

Tags: python-2.7, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, exacttarget

I am working with the FUEL SDK for Exact Target API. I have setup my enviorment variables but the app keeps denying me data, and throws the following error message

```
    raise Exception('Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: ' + repr(r.json()))
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {u'errorcode': 1, u'message': u'Unauthorized', u'documentation': u''}
```

I am looking in the client, but do not see why the authentication would be stopping. here is my code:

```
import os

os.environ["FUELSDK_CLIENT_ID"] = ""
os.environ["FUELSDK_CLIENT_SECRET"] = ""
os.environ["FUELSDK_DEFAULT_WSDL"] = "https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl"
os.environ
["FUELSDK_AUTH_URL"] = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken?legacy=1"
#os.environ["FUELSDK_WSDL_FILE_LOCAL_LOC"] = "C:\Users\Aditya.Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ExactTargetWSDL.s6.xml"


# Add a require statement to reference the Fuel SDK's functionality:
import FuelSDK

# Next, create an instance of the ET_Client class:
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client()

# Create an instance of the object type we want to work with:
list = FuelSDK.ET_List()

# Associate the ET_Client to the object using the auth_stub property:
list.auth_stub = myClient

# Utilize one of the ET_List methods:
response = list.get()

# Print out the results for viewing
print 'Post Status: ' + str(response.status)
print 'Code: ' + str(response.code)
print 'Message: ' + str(response.message)
print 'Result Count: ' + str(len(response.results))
print 'Results: ' + str(response.results)
```

Could someone please tell me why I am being shut out?

here is git repository I am using: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Client KEY/PWD in client.py

Comment: I keep getting ssl error any idea why?